# Laptop crashes while booting if battery is removed

Tags: bios, crash, battery, power, ilife

I have an old laptop that i decided to use as a media center for my TV. Since it would be used for long periods of time, 
with the power plugged in, it would damage the battery, so I removed the battery, and now if i try to power it on (with the power cord plugged in) it first instantly crashes, then restarts itself, loads up to the bios( posts)  then crashes again, then restarts again and loads up properly.

Incase its important, i also removed the integrated display of the laptop, and connecting it back made no difference.

I've tried looking in the bios if anything could fix this, and haven't found anything yet

Laptop model: iLife ZedAir H6

Comment: It is possible that the hardware circuit in the laptop that deals with battery charging and by-passing the battery (when there is no battery) is defective (hardware issue)

Comment: Could you add information on the _crash_? Does it ever load the kernel, do you see any boot information ...?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani the first time when it crashes, it does not output anything to the display. The second time, it loads up until the BIOS screen, and I can enter the BIOS, but as soon as the BIOS screen is done it crashes again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet (without spending money or getting any repairs would be to just leave the battery in the laptop, if you use it in the media center form most of the time. If you need to take it out regularly for normal use. If you need the latter, you should either re-flash or update the BIOS, as it might be a bug in the BIOS level.

Also, after researching the laptop, it seems it wasn't designed to have the battery removed. Most laptops that are designed to have the battery removed have easy remove latches on the bottom (and most of them are thick and bulky).

If you update the BIOS and your laptop DOES have any easy remove latch on the bottom, you might want to seek repairs and/or buy a media stick.